# Get id from clicked url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It is necessary for me at a choice the user of a subject of a forum on the page from a database contents of the chosen subject were loaded on the page. I will describe how I approached to the solution of this task. This code presents forum threads:

```
      <a href='Home/ThreadView' id='1'>About all</a>
      <a href='Home/ThreadView' id='2'>Cars</a>
```

ThreadView action has code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult ThreadView(int id)
    {
        ViewData[ThreadViewSelector] = Thread.GetThreadView(id);//Thread is a model.
        return View();
    }
```

When I click on any link an error occurs:

*Parameters dictionary contains record with value NULL for parameter "id" of type "System.Int32"*

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: The ids can be passed as `<a href='Home/ThreadView/1' id='1'>About all</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID attribute in your link is the id of the HTML element... so, that id could be useful if you want to do something with javascript.

With your current code, the id is never sent to the controller action, that is why the error you are seeing. You need to put the ID in the `href` attribute along with the Controller/Action.

You have 2 options to pass the id to your controller action:

- If you have the out-of-the-box routing rules you can use:

  `<a href='Home/ThreadView/1' id='1'>About all</a>`
- You can send it via query string this way:

  `<a href='Home/ThreadView/?id=1' id='1'>About all</a>`

**EDIT:**

- The element id is not required in order to have the routing working.

Instead of doing this manually, you could use one of the Razor Helpers:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About all", "Home", "ThreadView", new { id = 1})
```

If you need to add some attributes to the link element, besides the routing parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About all", "Home", "ThreadView", new { id = 1}, new { @class = "redLink", id="aboutall"})
```

Comment: How to me to share the concepts id of attribute and element id html of a code not to get confused further?

Comment: John, the element id is not required... just use it as a way to access that element by id. In your case is not required. In this case you are wrinting the link manually, but you could do as my editted answer.